Impedance of different track widths - Should I compute the average width?
Assume that you having one track that goes from 0.11mm in width to 0.09mm in width.
I want to compute the impedance, but I need to select the width. What option should I select?

The largest width of 0.11mm
The smallest width of 0.09mm
The average width of 0.1mm



It depends what is the purpose. If most of the track is wider and you have only 1 cm of narrow track, then the impedance of the narrow track may be irrelevant. The width change can also be for other compensating reasons to keep a constant impedance due to where the track goes to or if there are other changes as well, such as changes in the ground plane underneath the track.

The calculator needs the width as it affects the impedance. Therefore you should not change the width of the track mid-way if you want the impedance to be continuous.
Any discontinuity will cause reflections. Every time you change the width, a discontinuity is created, unless you change something else too, to compensate for the change.
Other important factor is that the reference plane (often GND) needs to be continuous in geometry too. You can't for example cut the plane underneath the track without affecting the impedance.
So the answer is you need to calculate the impedance for each width along the track.
Also, widths below 0.1 mm become trickier to manufacture, check with your circuit board manufacturer what the design rules should be.

or use 0.09mm instead all way long?

@euraad It might not be possible to reach the target impedance with 0.09mm width, as then you need a different PCB stackup with less distance between signal and ground planes.

@Justme Well, I'm locked to a specific stack. And I need to have 50 ohm as close as possible. It's for between MCU and Ethernet PHY.

@euraad then you can go with 0.09 mm, if your PCB manufacturer is ok with it. Some designs skip the layer directly below (by placing no copper pour where the track is) and use 3rd layer as the reference plane to get the geometry right.

@Ralph But can't I compute the average width? I mean, if I have 0.11 and 0.09, the middle is 0.1mm. Can't I go with that?

@euraad why do you even need 50 between MCU and PHY, is there a reason for that? And if you have two widths, then the first part will have impedance X and the other part has impedance Y, so taking the average of both sections makes no sense.

What @Ralph said is true,, basically  But whether or not it causes any measurable affects depends on the frequency (for RF signals) or the edge rate (for digital signals).  For things like RS-485 and even LVDS signals, we sometimes have to reduce the width of the traces when going through pin fields.  But we model & simulate most high speed interfaces as matter course and so know how neck downs affect signal quality.

Yeah, (R)MII is not that picky, it's just a plain digital interface and a little bounce is tolerable; you can adjust the source termination resistors; and trace length anyway needs to be much less than a full pulse duration to still meet timing requirements. If this is GMII or something, you'll want to check things more carefully.
